# How to test Reac Lazy inside an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs

At the project I'm working on, there's a few named exports like the object below:

```
export const object = {
    component: React.lazy(() => import('some-component'))
}
```

(They have more properties but I'll just show this one for brevity)

#### The issue

When I try to test it using Jest, I can't test inside React.lazy:

[image: Screenshot of coverage report]

I tried mocking React.lazy with no success:

```
jest.mock('react', () => ({
  lazy: () => {
    return 'lazy'
  },
}))

describe('Auth route object', () => {
  it('', () => {
    expect(auth).toBeDefined()
    expect(auth[0].component).toBe('lazy')
  })
})
```

This returns `passed` but it keeps complaining about coverage.

How can I mock/test that?

ps: I need at least 90% coverage on this file, that's why I can't just ignore it.

Comment: Mock the component, not React itself.

Comment: The only way I know how to mock a named export is like that: you import the default and mock it, returning itself (if needed) and it's named exports. I don't know how to mock just lazy.

Comment: Wait, I think I got it wrong, @EstusFlask (love the name btw). Are you telling me to mock 'some-component'?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Mock it and render a component that uses it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@testing-library/react` to test the `React.lazy()` method. In addition, if the lazy-loaded component is too complex and you only want to test the parent component that contains the component, you can use the `jest.mock()` method To provide a mocked version of the subcomponent.

E.g.

`index.tsx`:

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';

export const object = {
  component: React.lazy(() => import('./OtherComponent')),
};

export function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        <object.component />
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`OtherComponent.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';

export default function OtherComponent() {
  return <div>other component</div>;
}
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```
import { MyComponent } from './';
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';

function MockedOtherComponent() {
  return <div>mocked other component</div>;
}

jest.mock('./OtherComponent', () => {
  return MockedOtherComponent;
});

describe('67141439', () => {
  it('should pass', async () => {
    render(<MyComponent />);
    const textToMatch = await screen.findByText(/mocked other component/);
    expect(textToMatch).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/67141439/index.test.tsx (10.487 s)
  67141439
    ✓ should pass (40 ms)

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.tsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        12.745 s
```

package versions:

```json
"react": "^16.14.0"
"jest": "^26.6.3"
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
"@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
```

Comment: I'm already using this method. The isse is my company uses codeclimate and they calculate *very* unitary testing. So, this component is 100%, but the file itself is *still* 50% coverage and I need to cover that.